# OpenCV: src.depth() == dst.depth() && src.size == dst.size exception in task

Tags: c#, multithreading, opencv, emgucv

I have next code

```
private void crop_image(int i, int x, int y, int w, int h)
{
   Image<Bgr, Byte> loaded_image = new Image<Bgr, byte>(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\currentvideo\\image" + (i + 1) + ".jpg");
   Image<Bgr, Byte> croped_image = loaded_image.Copy(new Rectanle(x,y,w,h));
}
```

When i calling crop_image function, all works well.

```
for (int i = 0; i < crop_images_num; i++)
{
   crop_image(i, x,y,w,h);
}
```

But when i trying to use Task.Factory, i have exception

```
for (int i = 0; i < crop_images_num; i++)
{
   running.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => crop_image(i, x,y,w,h)));
   Task.WaitAll(running.ToArray());
}
```

I don't understand, what did i do wrong?

Comment: after loading try to test whether loaded image is empty (because loading failed)

Comment: What is your target .NET version (C# version)? Since you're using `Task.Factory.StartNew()` rather that `Task.Run()`, I suppose it's .NET 4.0 (C# 4.0). Right?

Comment: I'm using .Net 4.52. I solved problem by using threads. Have no idea, why i have bug trough Tasks (((